How do I change the default encoding of the integrated terminal in VS Code that is being used to connect to linux via SSH
I'm using VS Code in Windows 10 to work on a remote Linux server, using ssh. For specific reasons (that don't matter here) the remote server uses ISO-8859-1 for encoding. But unfortunately, the integrated terminal in VS Code transfers my input as UTF-8.
How do I change the way my input is encoded from UTF8 to ISO-8859-1?
Please keep in mind that I am not using the Terminal for a windows command line prompt (cmd.exe) or PowerShell prompt. That also means that using chcp.exe (like this: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/45520 ) won't work.
Edit:
Here is a minimal reproducible example:

Open VS Code
Install the Remote-SSH extension
Connect to your remote system using the remote explorer
Open a new terminal
Execute the command: echo -n ä | hexdump

Expected result if the input input is encoded in ISO-8859-1:
$ echo -n ä | hexdump
0000000 e400
0000001

Shown result using the terminal inside VS Code, showing that the input input is encoded in UTF-8:
$ echo -n ä | hexdump 
0000000 a4c3                                   
0000002


Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

I added the minimal reproducible example as requested.

Can you control the locale settings on the remote server? Does it support, say, LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8?

Unfortunately, I can only control my own locale settings on the server. But some applications need ISO8859-1 for their files and command line parameters. Since I need to use these applications and I don't have their source code, I need to use ISO8859-1 as encoding für my input. @triplee
